# How to read wikipedia offline after downloading enwiki-latest-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2

Tags: database, wikipedia

According to wikipedia document(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download), I used Bzreader, but it didn't work for such large file. How do I use this huge file properly for the purpose of using wikipedia offline?

Comment: If you just want to have an offline version of Wikipedia, you are better off using [Kiwix](http://www.kiwix.org/) instead of trying to reimplement the Wikipedia servers locally.